# MySQL SUM Query with Joins and Union All

Tags: mysql

Can anybody tell me why the second LEFT JOIN in the query below (previous_spend) is returning double the amount it should?

It returns the correct amount if I remove the first LEFT JOIN, so I assume it's doubling the result due to the first LEFT JOIN, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the query to avoid that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: I've created a slightly easier to understand version here: Here's a live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a9358/1 - as you can see 'current_spend' should return £300.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(current_spend.total_spend), 0) AS total_spend, 
    COALESCE(SUM(previous_spend.total_previous_spend), 0) AS total_previous_spend, 
    COALESCE(SUM(current_spend.total_spend), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(previous_spend.total_previous_spend), 0) AS total_spend_diff,
    100 * (COALESCE(SUM(current_spend.total_spend), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(previous_spend.total_previous_spend), 0)) / COALESCE(SUM(previous_spend.total_previous_spend), 0) AS total_spend_diff_perc
FROM customer_scheme

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2) AS total_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2017'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2018'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2019'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2) AS total_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2020'
    GROUP BY user_id
) as current_spend
    ON current_spend.user_id = customer_scheme.user_id

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2) AS total_previous_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2013'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_previous_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2014'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_previous_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2015'
    GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2) AS total_previous_spend, user_id
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year = '2016'
    GROUP BY user_id

) as previous_spend
    ON previous_spend.user_id = customer_scheme.user_id

LEFT JOIN user
    ON customer_scheme.user_id = user.user_id

WHERE customer_scheme.scheme_id = 36

AND customer_scheme.customer_scheme_access = 'Yes'
AND user.user_deleted_at IS NULL
AND user_type = 'Customer'
AND user.user_status IN (1)

ORDER BY total_spend_diff DESC
```

Comment: This is a big query so sample data that has the problem is very helpful.

Comment: Here's a live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a9358/1

Answer (score 0):

The summary of your query is

(customer_scheme LEFT JOIN current_spend) appended with (customer_scheme LEFT JOIN previous_spend)

**If you remove the LEFT JOIN with current_spend :**

Query would be customer_scheme LEFT JOIN previous_spend

That means, for one user in customer_scheme, you will get one row for previous_spend for 2013, one row for 2014, one row for 2015, one row for 2016

While summing, you will sum all the above said 4 rows.

**If you have the LEFT JOIN with current_spend :**

For first LEFT JOIN with current_spend, you will get one row for 2017, one for 2018, one for 2019 and one for 2020.

So, for one user_id , you will get 4 rows. Now, you are going to join previous_spend with these 4 rows (where as previously, you will join with only one row). While summing, this makes the difference.

I will try to provide much better insights if you can share an sql fiddle with some test data.

Comment: Any luck Praveen?

Comment: @CDR Please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a9358/2

I didn't understand why you are grouping in the subqueries. Understand why your query is performing in a wrong manner by using select *

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IFNULL(current_spend.total_spend, 0)) AS total_spend, 
    SUM(IFNULL(previous_spend.total_previous_spend, 0)) AS total_previous_spend, 
    SUM(IFNULL(current_spend.total_spend, 0)) - SUM(IFNULL(previous_spend.total_previous_spend, 0)) AS total_spend_diff,
    100 * (SUM(IFNULL(current_spend.total_spend, 0)) - SUM(IFNULL(previous_spend.total_previous_spend, 0))) / SUM(IFNULL(previous_spend.total_previous_spend, 0)) AS total_spend_diff_perc

FROM 

customer_scheme

LEFT JOIN 

(
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_spend, user_id, customer_spend.spend_year
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year in ('2017','2018','2019','2020') 
    GROUP BY user_id, customer_spend.spend_year
) as current_spend

    ON current_spend.user_id = customer_scheme.user_id

INNER JOIN

(
    SELECT SUM(spend_1 + spend_2 + spend_3 + spend_4 + spend_5 + spend_6 + spend_7 + spend_8 + spend_9 + spend_10 + spend_11 + spend_12) AS total_previous_spend, user_id, customer_spend.spend_year
    FROM customer_spend
    WHERE customer_spend.spend_year in ('2013','2014','2015','2016') 
    GROUP BY user_id, customer_spend.spend_year
) as previous_spend

    ON previous_spend.user_id = customer_scheme.user_id

LEFT JOIN user

    ON customer_scheme.user_id = user.user_id

WHERE customer_scheme.scheme_id = 36

AND customer_scheme.customer_scheme_access = 'Yes'
AND user.user_deleted_at IS NULL
AND user_type = 'Customer'
AND user.user_status IN (1)

ORDER BY total_spend_diff DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgive me for not providing enough information. In some cases this wouldn't work - for example if we only wanted spend_2 and spend_3 for a particular year. I'll update my post now.

Comment: Sorry I can't see your changes. What did you update?

Comment: Updated as a comment to the post